# What does percent sign with tilde syntax(%~a) mean in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

`for %a in (*.txt) do ren "%~a" "%~na version 1%~xa"`

This command line script can rename files in a directory by adding text ( `version 1`) to the end of filenames.

I'm wondering what do `%a`, `%~a`, `%~na`, `%~xa` syntax mean? Where can I find an introduction to these online?
Could you give me an online link to documentation?

Comment: The search engine SymbolHound.com is your friend here.

Comment: ...or this resource: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html); note that the same applies for [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variable references...

Comment: Why wouldn't you at least read the help for a command before asking a question about the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking the documentation for the `for` command:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

`%~a` means expand without quotes, `%~na` means filename only, `%~xa` means file extension only.

So `"%~a"` is the full name with quotes always around it, then the target is the existing name with "version 1" inserted between the name and the extension.